# Is the space metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{(x,y): x=0 \text{ or } y=0\}$ be the subset of the Euclidean space $(R^{2},Te)$. Analyze the quotient space $(R^{2}/A,T^*)$ obtained by "glueing" all the points from A to one point. Is this quotient space metrizable? How to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not metrizable. To see that suppose it is. Let $\pi :\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2/A$, then $\pi (A)$ has to have countable base $B=\{U_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ at point $A$. By definition of quotient topology $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ is open. Now pick sequence of elements $(x_i)\subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $x_i\in \pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $x_i=(i+1,y_i)$ for some $y_i$. Its easy to see you can do that. This gives you contradiction because $\pi (\mathbb R^2-\{x_i\}_i)$ is a neighbourhood of $\pi(A)$ witch does not contain any of the sets $U_i$.